# Использовать цикл с предусловием

Tags: pascal

Не понимаю поставленой задачи, точнее не знаю как это использовать цикл с предусловием в паскале.

```
Program PROIZVED;
var N, i, P: byte;
BEGIN
write('vedite N= ');
readln(N);
P:=1;
For i:=1 to N do
P:=P*i;
writeln('PROIZVED= ',P:5);
readln;
END.
```

Comment: как целиком звучит ваша задача? Спросить  того, кто ее поставил, не пробовали?

Comment: @teran Хочешь прикол наш препод по информатике сам не знает) Я бы тогда здесь не спрашивал. Ну а полное условие Задача 1. Знайти доданок всіх натуральних чисел від 1 до N ( ). Використати цикл з передумовою.

Comment: _while < условие> do <оператор 1>;  {Пока … делай ….}_

Comment: да, я в целом тоже за `while-do`. _зы: произведение от 1 до N факториалом называется обычно._

Comment: @teran Да я читал об этом в нете но не знаю куда while и do подставлять

Comment: @teran, так-то _доданок_ - слагаемое, то есть речь о сумме была

Comment: @BraFik, вместо `for`

Comment: @Grundy Ага кажется я понял спасибо

Comment: @Grundy ну я хз, в коде было умножение :) да и программа называется `PROIZVED` :)

Comment: @teran, скорее всего решение для другого варианта :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл с предусловием - это когда сначала проверяется условие, а потом (если условие вернуло true) программа заходит в тело цикла

```
x:=0;
while (x>10) do begin
  x:=x+1;
  writeln(x);
end;
```

Цикл с постусловием - когда сначала выполняется тело цикла (минимум 1 раз) и потом проверяется условие, например:

```
x:=0;
repeat
  x:=x+1;
  writeln(x);
until (x>10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Program PROIZVED;
  var N, i, P: byte;
BEGIN
  write('vedite N= ');
  readln(N);
  P:=1;
  i:=1;
  while (i<N) do 
  begin
    P:=P*i;
    i:=i+1;
  end;
  writeln('PROIZVED= ',P:5);
  readln;
END.
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]